# Report portal integration with cucumber6 - Results doesnt show in test launches

Tags: cucumber-java, reportportal

Results doesn't show in test launches

agent-java-cucumber6 - 5.1.3

cucumber-java - 6.0.0

In test runner plugin = {"pretty","json:target/cucumber.json","html:target/cucumber-    report/cucumber.html","com.epam.reportportal.cucumber.ScenarioReporter"}

And created reportportal.properties file within root folder

RP version - Build: 5.2.3
Using maven

Please let me know if I need to provide any additional info`